# glm() error contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I am creating a logistic regression model using some data set. Despite removing factors containing only one level I am still getting the error:

```
> fit <- glm(Intraop_Blood_Products ~ ., family = binomial(), na.action = na.omit, data = rel_data)
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Although I cannot share the particular composition of the data. The function *str(rel_data)* shows that all factor variables contain two or more levels. Additionally, I tried using *complete_case_data <- rel_data[complete.cases(rel_data),]* to remove all NAs from the data set as another user suggested that glm() could be throwing this error due to the presence of NAs, yet the error persists. If you could offer any insight please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: a factor can have two or more levels but only one level present in the data ex -  `factor(c("a"),levels = c("a","b"))` .  check the amount of unique values actually present in your data.

Comment: Solved the issue. Initially na.omit would remove rows containing NAs which resulted in a data set which previously had categorical variables labelled as having two or more factor levels to have only one after then rows were eliminated. The same happened for complete.cases(). I had to check summary(complete_case_data) for each variable to identify the issue.